# USB HID failing to install on Rasp Pi wheezy since upgrade

Tags: usb, debian, raspberry-pi, libusb

I recently updated my raspberry pi which runs my home heating system via a USB relay. Since then the machine halts on boot whilst trying to install this USB device, stopping at the Manufacturer message and not showing the timeout until I unplug it.

Here is my output from /var/log/messages

```
Jun  2 21:25:42 raspberrypi kernel: [  297.841335] usb 1-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 6 using dwc_otg
Jun  2 21:25:42 raspberrypi kernel: [  297.947754] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=12bf, idProduct=ff03
Jun  2 21:25:42 raspberrypi kernel: [  297.947878] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Jun  2 21:25:42 raspberrypi kernel: [  297.947969] usb 1-1.2: Product: Flowcode USB HID
Jun  2 21:25:42 raspberrypi kernel: [  297.948055] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: Matrix Multimedia Ltd.
Jun  2 21:25:52 raspberrypi kernel: [  307.970899] hid-generic 0003:12BF:FF03.0004: timeout initializing reports
Jun  2 21:25:52 raspberrypi kernel: [  307.973809] hid-generic 0003:12BF:FF03.0004: hiddev0,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Device [Matrix Multimedia Ltd. Flowcode USB HID] on usb-bcm2708_usb-1.2/input0
Jun  2 21:25:56 raspberrypi kernel: [  311.944883] usb 1-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 6
Jun  2 21:28:06 raspberrypi kernel: [  441.223708] usb 1-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 7 using dwc_otg
Jun  2 21:28:06 raspberrypi kernel: [  441.329935] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=12bf, idProduct=ff03
Jun  2 21:28:06 raspberrypi kernel: [  441.330109] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Jun  2 21:28:06 raspberrypi kernel: [  441.330226] usb 1-1.2: Product: Flowcode USB HID
Jun  2 21:28:06 raspberrypi kernel: [  441.330282] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: Matrix Multimedia Ltd.
Jun  2 21:28:16 raspberrypi kernel: [  451.383446] hid-generic 0003:12BF:FF03.0005: timeout initializing reports
Jun  2 21:28:16 raspberrypi kernel: [  451.386313] hid-generic 0003:12BF:FF03.0005: hiddev0,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Device [Matrix Multimedia Ltd. Flowcode USB HID] on usb-bcm2708_usb-1.2/input0
```

Appreciate any pointers on how to fix this, as it was working prior to the apt-get upgrade.

Note that everything works if I wait until the login prompt before adding the USB device. Although, not at all ideal!

Thanks